# Spring Transaction propogation and rollback behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

```
@Service
public Class Demo(){

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=CustomException.class)
    @Override
    public RetunType methodONE()throws Exception{
        methodTWO();
        methodFIVE();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public RetunType methodTWO()throws Exception{
            methodFOUR();
            methodTHREE();
            throws new CustomException("error_msg");
        }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public RetunType methodTHREE(){
        .
        ..
        .
        ..
        .
    }
 }

 public Class CustomException  extends Exception{

    public CustomException(String msg){
        super(msg)
    }
 }
```

I don't want to roll back only my methodThree transaction. Now it is rolling back all changes made in methodTWO/THREE/FOUR/FIVE. I am unable to understand further.

*I am trying to do transactions related code in all other methods and in methodThree() it's just status updating in DB.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do here is have methodTHREE run inside it's own transaction nested inside a parent transaction, your problem is probably that the methods are in the same class.

This matters because of the way Spring applies AOP, in this instance by applying transactional logic, using proxies to intercept method calls. The problem is the method call is internal or is self-invocating, and so never goes through the proxy. This means a new transaction is never created for MethodThree().

You have two options:

1. Move method Three to a separate class.
2. Change the mode from proxy to AspectJ, which will weave the transactional logic into the class itself.

[Spring Doc for @Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Comment: **with option 1 my nested transaction result obtained successfully**

Comment: Good, I thought it might. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped solve your problem. Thanks.